# Retrieving files from unbootable Ubuntu drive

Tags: windows-8, files

I tried to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 last night and something went wrong. At first I was able to boot to the log-in screen, but it was showing a blank screen with a cursor.

I used boot-repair to attempt to fix the issue and now it only shows a blank screen. I want to format and install 14.04, but I cannot access my files through the "Try Ubuntu" option as suggested. When I try to copy the files over to another HDD or external HDD I get a permission denied message.

I've just installed Ext2 on my Windows 8 HDD, but it doesn't allow me to view the files without formatting first.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Please review http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask and help us help you! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Boot from live media (CD/DVD/USB)

Step 2: mount the partitions that contain the files you need (NTFS if they are from Windows 8) 
See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation) and try to apply the solutions there for Windows 8

Then if you have permissions problems accessing the files open a terminal and issue the command

`gksu nautilus` which will open the file browser with administrative rights (AKA root access) allowing you to copy off the files as needed.